# What is the difference between Framework Service Providers and Application Service Providers?

Tags: laravel

In the file `config/app.php` there is an array key 'providers'. This contains the different service providers. Laravel divides here between: Package Service Providers, Application Service Providers and Framework Service Providers.

I just had to add an external package (Spatie Permission). Here I have to add the spatie PermissionServiceProvider into this array.  It doesn't matter where you add it but I still wanted to know what is the diffenece between Framwork Service-, Application Service and Package Service. To finally put the `Spatie\Permission\PermissionServiceProvider::class,` in the right place. I use Laravel 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The categorisation of service providers mentioned is only with respect to the source of the provider. All service providers work the same way, regardless of source. Here's a breakdown of what these are:

1. Application service providers are your own providers typically in the `\App\Providers` namespace. The Laravel boilerplate app comes with 5 by default (listed [here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/8.x/app/Providers)) and they are boilerplate in the sense that they provide basic app functionality but are meant to be extended and modified by the developer.
2. Framework package providers are the ones that Laravel ships with. They are typically under the `Illuminate` namespace though the exact namespace may very depending on their purpose. These usually provide critical framework functionality and should not be removed or prevented from running.
3. Package service providers are ones that originate from 3rd party packages like for example the one from laravel permission at `Spatie\Permission\PermissionServiceProvider::class`

#### Creating providers

Application providers can be created using the command

```
php artisan make:provider ProviderName
```

This creates a new provider under `app/Providers` but does not register it.

#### Registering service providers

Application and framework service providers (as well as some package service providers) are registered in `config/app.php` under the `providers` section. This allows the developer to control the order in which they run. Prior to Laravel 5.5 package service providers also needed to be registered in the `config/app.php`.

These providers are used to build a provider cache which is stored under `bootstrap/cache` which is what is actually read and used to bootstrap Laravel

#### Package auto-discovery

Since Laravel 5.5 the following command has been added to Laravel

```
php artisan package:discover
```

This command goes through the vendor folder looking for sections in the composer.json that contain something like:

```
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "providers": [
            "PackageVendor\\PackageName\\ServiceProvider"
        ],
    }
},
```

This is then used to add the additional providers to the bootstrap provider cache without the developer needing to manually add them in the `config/app.php`

This command is set up to run after a `composer autoload-dump` in the boilerplate Laravel app which generally runs after most composer operations.

#### Running providers

All providers that are included in the bootstrap provider cache run in the order they are defined in by first calling `register` on each of them and then calling `boot` on each of them.

#### Deferred providers

Information on deferred providers can be found [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/providers#deferred-providers). The short version is if your provider only provides bindings to the service container you can defer the running of the provider only when the bindings are actually required.